# Making a CFG for $a^{i}b^{j}c^{k}$ such that $i+j=k+3, i,j\geq1$

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar

I have the language $$ L=\{a^{i}b^{j}c^{k} \mid i+j= k+3, i,j\geq1\} $$however I am struggling to convert it to a CFG. I ended up with this grammar:
\begin{align}
 S &\rightarrow aSc \mid aBAc \mid B\\
 A &\rightarrow bAc \mid bc \\
 B &\rightarrow aaa \mid aab\mid abb\mid bbb \\
\end{align}

Is it correct?

Comment: Questions of the form "am I right?" are not very useful. In cases like this, you can often find the negative answer yourself, by just trying a few derivations. For example, $S\to aAc\to aaAbc\to aaBbcbc\to aaaaabcbc$. (All derivations use the first alternative except the second derivation of $A$.)

Comment: Also, note that $abb$ is in the target language since $k$ is not required to be positive. So if the top-level rule requires the string to end with $c$, it cannot be correct.

Comment: You are right, i will check that. Thanks

Comment: What do you think about this one?

Comment: I think my first two comments still apply (without the detailed example). In other words, get out a pad of paper and a pencil, and do some derivations. (It's closer, though, in some sense.)

Comment: I will do that, thanks